# VS code cursor getting in insert mode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been struggling to switch the cursor mode from insert to normal all the time. it was all start happen when I was installed VIM extension in VS code. But I was completely unaware of why this happening suddenly to the code editor. After searching the google I found that VIM extension overriding the cursor properties to VS code.

I have uninstalled the VIM extension and the problem get rid away.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simply uninstall VIM extension from VS code.

Comment: I removed VIM extension and VSCode still always places me in overtype mode which I cannot stand. How can one specifically DISABLE overtype mode forever for every single document, all projects, etc!?