# My cursor isn't functioning properly on VS Code. I'm unable to type anything, and I'm using a MacBook Air

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, cursor, execution, typing

My cursor isn't functioning properly on VS Code and I'm not able to type anything. Can someone help? For context, I'm using a MacBook Air.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jipTh.png)

I tried restarting VS Code and it's still the same, I haven't faced this problem before so I'm not quite sure how to approach it.

Comment: What extensions do you have installed? Can you show your full interface and your user and workspace settings?

Comment: Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if you have the [VIM](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim) extension installed, this extension has reportedly been known to cause the 'overtype' symptom that your image displays.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67230920/vs-code-cursor-getting-in-insert-mode) answer or [even here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67981861/vs-code-cursor-keep-going-into-overtype-mode/72617523#72617523).

In both of these references, the solution has been to uninstall the extension.

Comment: for this kind of suggestion, I'd probably dup-vote instead of answering. see the "flag" button.